# mysql stored procedure, select max value and insert the value and assign to variable

Tags: mysql, sql, multithreading, stored-procedures, thread-safety

I am porting a MSSQL stored procedure to MYSQL and i have a stored procedure that does this.

1. get the last value in a table by select Max.
2. add the new value to the table (along with other record
3. get the last value and store it in a variable for other processing

So far what i have the following

```
     DECLARE lastSeq INT Default 0;

     SELECT max(seq) INTO lastSeq from mytable;

     Set newSeq = lastSeq + 1;    
     insert into mytable (seq, value1, value2, value3) values (newSeq, 1, 2, 3);
```

Unfortunately this is NOT thread safe, say if I select max(seq) and then a new record was added by other thread running a different query, by the time i reach insert, the value is already wrong.
In MSSQL I did this by locking the table during query of max(seq).

BUT

MYSQL does not allow locking of tables in stored procedure, so I cannot directly port the approach.
Havent had the luck to find solution while searching, maybe i am not putting the right keywords in search.

How can I do this in MYSQL thread safe inside stored procedure?

Update: I cannot use auto_increment for this column as this column is not unique and we allow duplicate, maybe my sample is wrong since i used "sequence" which should be auto increment, but in my real code, i use it for a different column that allows duplication.

example;

```
     record id userid     name  seq   status
     1      1      adam   1     A
     2      1      adam   2     C
     3      2      Bob    1     C
```

In the above record, we have 2 records for Adam but only one valid set to "C" as current and "A" as archived or old value.
so my table has 2 valid record,

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long for a comment.

So change the data type to be `auto_increment`.  There is no need to do re-implement this logic in a trigger, when the database basically does it for you.

If you are concerned about gaps, then just use `row_number() over (order by seq)` when you query the table.

Comment: well i cant use auto increment for this column because there are instances that the column can be the same value as it is not unique.
Example, one column is "status" that just update the column if its the valid or the old value for record keeping.

my example maybe wrong as it is "sequence" which should be auto increment, but my real SP uses it differently. I Updated my original post